# People Picker Does not show the correct profile info from AD

Tags: user-profile, people-picker

In one of the Sharepoint 2010 site People picker is not populating a specific profile with correct info. The email id and other fields, except name, is blank though the details are properly set in AD. I tried to delete and create the profile again in User profile service. It didn't make any difference. PP of that site is still showing the profile with incomplete info. Hence I am facing difficulties in adding the ID for generating certain alerts. Is there any solution which would resolve this issue?

Note : Other sites of the same farm is populating the profile as expected and resolving the names correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved. The properties of the account has been updated by script and then added the user id under some random group. Then, it has been deleted from the site collection. The account details were populated as expected.